# how to integrate CMS component of Liferay in a Spring java application?

Tags: spring-mvc, content-management-system, liferay-6, drools-guvnor

I have very dynamic content for each section of the web portal.The rules for that content are stored in the rule engine drools along with the content,Now I want to separate the content part from drools so as to make content editable via UI. Liferay has been opted as CMS.

I need to use only CMS component of Liferay along with the rules to be managed by drools in a spring-MVC java application having Angularjs framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can develop a Liferay portlet wich manages the Liferay content and a java project with the drools part. If you need to use drools on the cms part, you can import that on your portlet as a jar.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but It is not possible to develop complete application on Liferay ,as requirements are not as such. The application is now running without CMS now i need to manage content part in CMS instead of drools.

Comment: With Liferay, it's possible to create web services, you can look here https://www.liferay.com/es/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Web+Services+via+SOAP.

Comment: Thanks for the link it helped me to research more on this, I have found JSON webservices to be a better option as we are using JSON, https://www.liferay.com/es/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/JSON+Web+Services#section-JSON+Web+Services-Registering+JSON+Web+Services